# How to get some lines after a matched line using shell command

Tags: bash, sed

I have a config with contents like this

```
[a]
url1
url2

[b]
url3
url4
```

the line after section is variable. How can I get the lines of a section.

Comment: This gets close: `sed -n "'/\[a]/,/\[.*]/p" your_file`. By the way, if you're using the `bash` shell, you should tag `bash` as it gets a lot more traffic than just `shell`.

Comment: @lurker but  both [a] and [b] is printed, can I only print URL after [a] before [b]

Comment: It was a comment to help get you started, which is why I did not post it as a complete answer. I didn't want to do all of your work for you. :) You should experiment a bit and think about how to get rid of the `[a]` and `[b]` in my example. It does narrow it down already to the section you want'.

Answer (score 1):

In the `sed` command, there is a way to use a loop.

```
sed -n '/\[a\]/{:x;n;s/\[.\]//;t;p;b x;}' inputfile
```

Using `awk` command, the command is follwoing:

```
awk '/\[.\]/{f=0}f==1{print $0}/\[a\]/{f=1}' inputfile
```

*The order in which the patterns appear is important.*

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\[a\]/{:a;p;n;/^\[/!ba}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n` since this is a filter operation.

When a line starting `[a]` is encountered, print it and fetch the next line an if that line does not begin `[` repeat.

An alternative:

```
sed '/^\[/h;G;/^\[a\]/MP;d' file
```

If a blank line defines the end of a section:

```
sed -n '/^\[a\]/{:a;p;n;/^\[\|^$/!ba}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If your blank lines do not contain any whitespace, then `awk` is well suited to the task.  If the blank lines do contain whitespace, you should prefilter the input so they do not:

```
$ cat input

[a]
url1
url2

[b]
url3
url4
$ awk '$1=="[a]"' RS= input
[a]
url1
url2
$ awk '$1=="[b]"' RS= input
[b]
url3
url4
```